# How to append a word 'COPY' into reducer state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to add word "Copy" in my reducer object.

WidgetList is an array of objects.which consists of `[{widgettype:'barchart' widgetName:'Widget'}]`, output accepted: `[{widgettype:'barchart' widgetName:'copy-Widget'}]`

When i click on the duplicate button i am able to get the duplicate items clearly to differentiate between the duplicate and original widget. Need to add 'Copy'Word' in front of widgetName.

Here is my code:

```
// Reducer

case types.DUPLICATE_DATA:
    const duplicatedWidget = {
      ...widgetToDuplicate,
      widgetId: uuid(),
    };
    return { ...state,
        boardList: [...newBoardList]
    };
```

Comment: You mean prepend? Why not something like `duplicatedWidget = { ...widgetToDuplicate, widgetName: 'COPY+' + widgetToDuplicate.widgetName }`

Comment: can we add count for this say  "COPY1+ Widget"  "COPY2+ Widget"

Comment: Sure, if your widget would have a unique name, now, if people duplicate from the copied widget, it's unique name wouldn't be the widget itself, but already copyxxx. So either you would have to go through all widgets and check the highest copy(x)-widget and increase by one, or you keep an id for each copy but you would need some kind of check then if the name has already copy in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like,

```
case types.DUPLICATE_DATA:
        var str = widgetToDuplicate.widgetName;
        var copyStr = str.match(/copy\([0-9]+\)$/g);
       if(copyStr){
         var number = parseInt(copyStr[copyStr.length-1].match(/[0-9]+/g)[0]);
         str = str.replace(copyStr, "copy("+(number+1) +")")
       }
       else str = str+'-copy(1)';
        const duplicatedWidget = {
          ...widgetToDuplicate,
          widgetName: str,
          widgetId: uuid(),
        };
    return { ...state,
      boardList: [...newBoardList]
    };
```

Comment: Murali - when i click 5 duplicate - it gives "Widget-copy-copy-copy-copy-copy"

Comment: can we append count here??say "Widget1","Widget2"

Comment: yes,  you will have to do a string search for "copy" and then parseInt the number after that and append this string

Comment: need to search in redux itself,need to change in action as well?? can you please update in your answer

Comment: Before `const duplicatedWidget= ...` process the newName by finding the `copy(number)` from `widgetToDuplicate.widgetName`. And then, increment the number and reassign.

Comment: Sorry Can you please brief me more on this.new to react

Comment: Thanks Rohit it helped me a lot

Comment: Cool. Glad i could help \ (•◡•) /